# java LDAPs authenticate performance

Tags: java, ldap

I have a simple java application which is doing usual ldap operations. I saw that authenticate method is 10 times slower for LDAPs than for LDAP.

Is it normal?

Is it possible to improve the performance?

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.directory.*;
import javax.naming.ldap.*;


class Ldap {

    private LdapContext ctx;
    private String url;

    public Ldap(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void authenticate(String user, String pass) throws NamingException {

        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pass);

        ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
    }
}


public class App {
    static DirContext ldapContext;
    public static void main (String[] args) throws NamingException  {

        long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Ldap ldap = new Ldap(args[0]);

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            ldap.authenticate("username", "password");
        }
        long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time:" + (after-before) + " msec");
    }
}
```

The results:

```
$ java -jar ldap.jar ldap://ldapserver.hq.k.grp:389
Time:739 msec
$ java -jar ldap.jar ldaps://ldapserver.hq.k.grp:636
Time:7546 msec
```

When I dump the threads in my application I can see that it is always waiting in the same place:

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000026be000 nid=0x20a0 in Object.wait() [0x0000000002ade000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000d6524678> (a com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapRequest)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.readReply(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000d6524678> (a com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapRequest)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.ldapBind(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000d64f9048> (a com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000d64f9048> (a com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.nagra.Ldap.authenticate(App.java:29)
    at com.nagra.App.main(App.java:45)
```

The other LDAP operations like get users in group are 2 times slower for LDAPS.

Comment: establishing an SSL connection isn't  cheap, I would ensure you open a connection once and retain it. each authenticate is < 75 ms which doesn't appear to be too long. Which LDAP server are you using?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey It's a corporate ldap server. I don't know exactly the details. Is it normal that other ldap operations are 2 times slower? Like getting users in group.

Comment: some operations are slower than others, some ldap servers are slower than others. It used to be the case that Active Directory was pretty slow, not sure if it still is. If Java is waiting, most likely the server you are talking to is taking it's time.